# Extract all allowed characters from a regular expression

Tags: regex, string

I need to extract a list of all allowed characters from a given regular expression.

So for example, if the regex looks like this (some random example):

```
[A-Z]*\s+(4|5)+
```

the output should be

```
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ45
```

(omitting the whitespace)

One obvious solution would be to define a complete set of allowed characters, and use a `find` method, to return the corresponding subsequence for each character. This seems to be a bit of a dull solution though.

Can anyone think of a (possibly simple) algorithm on how to implement this?

Comment: Do you need the code (in which language?) or just an idea? Have you already thought to something?

Comment: I'm actually just looking for an idea. The language it is in is not that important.

Comment: So basically you are asking for an algorithm which is known as regex interpreter... I don't think you will get any correct answer.... What you really need to do is know regex very very well ( if you don't) and implement your interpretter accordingly. And the algorithm would be, to start reading from the left of the regex and read until end of the regex and while doing so interpret the current and preceding and following chars

Comment: yes, you are right. that's basically what I need. I was hoping that someone had a similar problem already and found an elegant solution for it

Comment: No easy solution here ... your task would be near to making a regex engine ... unless you find any open source one ( which you may google a bit)

Comment: Thought so already. But I figured I'd ask ;) Thanks

Comment: One Java library I stumbled upon is able to perform the task. But since it is not an answer to the question, I will post it as a comment, as it might help someone:

http://www.brics.dk/automaton/index.html

With this you can do `Automaton automaton = new RegExp(regex).toAutomaton();`, and then retrieve a set of characters with `Set<String> strings = automaton.singleChars().getFiniteStrings();`

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is:

- split the regex by subgroup
- test the char panel against the subgroup

See the following example (not perfect yet) [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23):

```
static void Main(String[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"-->{TestRegex(@"[A-Z]*\s+(4|5)+")}<--");
}

public static string TestRegex(string pattern)
{
    string result = "";
    foreach (var subPattern in Regex.Split(pattern, @"[*+]"))
    {
        if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(subPattern))
            continue;
        result += GetAllCharCoveredByRegex(subPattern);
    }
    
    return result;
}

public static string GetAllCharCoveredByRegex(string pattern)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Testing {pattern}");
    var regex = new Regex(pattern);
    var matches = new List<char>();
    for (var c = char.MinValue; c < char.MaxValue; c++)
    {

        if (regex.IsMatch(c.ToString()))
        {
            matches.Add(c);
        }
    }
    return string.Join("", matches);
}
```

Which outputs:

> Testing [A-Z]
>
> Testing \s
>
> Testing (4|5)
>
> -->ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
>
> ? ?       ???????? 45<--

Comment: That's what I thought of at first as well. But it would have to be refined quite a lot in order to cover the whole regex syntax (i.e. the ECMAScript regex syntax).
It is also rather slow, since testing all characters is quite time consuming

Comment: @super-qua this is a brute force approach and, by definition will be slow. It have the advantage to not need to write a regex parser...

Comment: Yes, that's correct of course, I didn't mean to say that this answer is not correct. But it's more or less the approach I mentioned in the question already